# qsort() doesnot work with an array of long integers

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, qsort

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(long*)a - *(long*)b );
}

int main()
{
    long arr[50] = {
    96998584605411,40693566272356,
    8867531321455,71374670306442,
    57352857357994,1788166056027,
    63349502945247,59799324891707,
    26353174130397,39181960858171,
    88760729874506,77735622774927,
    65389382041144,83564210278376,
    34210610714041,25960810689062,
    30915481991565,46863920152180,
    39693165577270,81307468736394,
    20993925693066,14707273086616,
    51940778082526,28031438753382,
    51923056867661,16931703600607,
    31109898828992,89599450093153,
    34498804713695,36774523858020,
    65593865433917,39538286624853,
    63312447540821,18796138114716,
    64794317568658,85850552382870,
    56557892707211,72388843001640,
    46583476931914,38539500078935,
    95031088595551,88735420786323,
    87050672468742,13877728078926,
    25045274978126,64616891994055,
    67682298778152,16659227331485,
    41265109202214,77090119561917
    };
    qsort(arr, 50, sizeof(long), compare);
    printf("Values are\n");
    int i ;
    for (i=0; i< 50; i++)
        printf("%ld\n", arr[i]);
}
```

prints its output without sorting properly

Values are

```
39538286624853
39693165577270
81307468736394
20993925693066
46583476931914
87050672468742
30915481991565
63312447540821
64794317568658
95031088595551
13877728078926
38539500078935
71374670306442
16931703600607
36774523858020
96998584605411
65593865433917
34210610714041
51923056867661
14707273086616
25045274978126
83564210278376
18796138114716
88735420786323
31109898828992
1788166056027
72388843001640
46863920152180
34498804713695
51940778082526
56557892707211
25960810689062
89599450093153
57352857357994
67682298778152
28031438753382
8867531321455
85850552382870
65389382041144
63349502945247
40693566272356
39181960858171
16659227331485
41265109202214
64616891994055
26353174130397
77090119561917
59799324891707
88760729874506
77735622774927
```

What am I doing wrong to print the **qsorted** array wrong?

Comment: Integer overflow. The difference between two longs doesn't fit in an int.

Comment: `*(long*)a - *(long*)b` What type do you suppose the difference is?

Comment: I change the code(return type of qsort to long), but no difference in the output . ```long compare (const void * a, const void * b)```

Comment: You might carefully read [qsort(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) and study its source code in e.g. [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). You should enable all warnings and debug info at compilation time. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g your-code.c -o your-prog` then use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) on `your-prog`. Consider also using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)

Comment: NO — you are NOT allowed to change the code to invalidate your own question.  And you're not allowed to pass a function pointer to a function that returns a `long` to a function that expects a function pointer to a function that returns an `int`, either (more UB).

Comment: And read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: Resubmitting a comment with corrected code: Integer overflow in your comparison function — undefined behaviour. Don't use subtraction — it's lazy and doesn't work properly when the numbers are big enough in magnitude and of opposite signs. Either do it longhand: `int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2) { long v1 = *(long *)p1; long v2 = *(long *)p2; if (v1 < v2) return -1; else if (v1 > v2) return +1; else return 0; }` or use the shorthand: `int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2) { long v1 = *(long *)p1; long v2 = *(long *)p2; return (v1 > v2) - (v1 < v2); }` — Sorry about the glitch!

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, Thanks , It worked. Can I ask why the difference between two ``` long``` variables can't be returned in a function which is of ```long``` return type eg: ```long compare(const void *a, const void *b){ return  *(long*)a - *(long*)b; }

Comment: If the function returns `long`, you can run into (long) integer overflow if one value is big and negative and the other is big and positive.  That's one problem.  The other problem is that `qsort()` expects a function pointer matching `int (*cmp)(const void *p1, const void *p2)`, so if your function returns `long`, not `int`, it is the wrong type to pass to `qsort()`.  You are clearly on a 64-bit machine (or a machine with `long` using at least 64-bits), so `int` is a 32-bit type and `long` is a 64-bit type — the wrong type of function pointer will not work reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning a compare that may 1) overflow or 2) the difference does not fit in an `int`

```
//return ( *(long*)a - *(long*)b );
return (*(long*)a > *(long*)b)  -   *(long*)a < *(long*)b);
```